# How can I convert pivoted columns into rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, unpivot

I have a table which contains result like

```
Donna F. Carreras|Alexander J. Deborde|John  Ford|Marjorie M. Lee| Crystal C Zhu
176          |    246         |     312  |           502 |    19969
```

And I want it to be shown like:

```
176     Donna F. Carreras
246     Alexander J. Deborde
312     John Ford
502     Marjorie M. Lee
19969   Crystal C Zhu
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server you can apply the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function:

```
select value, col
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in ([Donna F. Carreras], [Alexander J. Deborde], 
              [John Ford], [Marjorie M. Lee], [Crystal C Zhu])
) un
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41ed5/1)

Or you can use a `UNION ALL` query:

```
select [Donna F. Carreras] value, 'Donna F. Carreras' col
from yourtable
union all
select [Alexander J. Deborde] value, 'Alexander J. Deborde' col
from yourtable
union all
select [John Ford] value, 'John Ford' col
from yourtable
union all
select [Marjorie M. Lee] value, 'Marjorie M. Lee' col
from yourtable
union all
select [Crystal C Zhu] value, 'Crystal C Zhu' col
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41ed5/2)

Both produce the same result:

```
| VALUE |                  COL |
--------------------------------
|   176 |    Donna F. Carreras |
|   246 | Alexander J. Deborde |
|   312 |            John Ford |
|   502 |      Marjorie M. Lee |
| 19969 |        Crystal C Zhu |
```

Comment: thanks it worked ... thanks again for your time you spent to give an answer @bluefeet